# Invalid IL code when calling a native linux library from a .NET application running under mono in CentOS

Tags: .net, linux, mono, dllimport

I am trying to use the Intel MKL libraries in a multiplatform context. I've got my DllImports and wrapper class working under .NET/Windows. However when I port that to CentOS, I get "Invalid IL code".

I have changed the DLLImports to include the linux version of MKL (a .so library). I added the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. Still, the error does not change whether the libraries are there or not. And I am not getting DLLNotFound error, I get an invalid IL error.

Below I paste my windows, working dllimport statement.

```
[DllImport("mkl_rt.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern int DftiCreateDescriptor(
        ref IntPtr handle_descriptor,
        int precision,
        int domain,
        int dime,
        int size
    );
```

And now here is what I came up with for linux

```
[DllImport("libmkl_rt.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int DftiCreateDescriptor(
        ref IntPtr handle_descriptor,
        int precision,
        int domain,
        int dime,
        int size
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually this was solved by not using __arg_list and using the Mono ".config" file